# Routes not mapping correctly when creating in memory web api server

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api

When I curl to the `/test` route it works fine, however the test below 404's when trying to hit the in memory server on the same route.

When inspecting `_client` and `_config` appear to be ok - although I am not sure how to confirm that my in memory server is functioning correctly.

Does anybody know how I can get my in memory web server to map it's routes correctly so my test method can reach it?

```
namespace Robo.Tests.Controllers
{

    [TestClass]
    public class IntegrationTests
    {
        private HttpMessageInvoker _client;
        private HttpConfiguration _config = new HttpConfiguration();

        [TestInitialize]
        public void SetupTest()
        {
            _config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            _config.EnsureInitialized();

            var server = new HttpServer(_config);
            _client = new HttpMessageInvoker(server);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public async Task Test()
        {
            var result = await _client.SendAsync(new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://localhost/test"), CancellationToken.None);
        }
    }
}
```

and controller in case you are interested

```
namespace Robo.Controllers
{
    //[ValidationActionFilter]
    public class CVController : ApiController
    {

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("test")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> test()
        {
            return Ok();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe in-memory test server listens to localhost. so it would be `http://localhost/test/test` assuming that the route was {controller}/{action}

Comment: just tried changing to localhost and still 404ing

Comment: Is the controller and test in the same assembly? Include the controller class definition.

Comment: both of them are now in the exact same namespace and it is still 404ing

Comment: same namespace and same assembly mean different things. update code for controller with class definition.

Comment: what does `ValidationActionFilter` do. could it be denying the request?

Comment: it does modelstate validation - have commented it out and still 404ing. Will update code above with the comment.

Comment: Here is the thing. you need to provide a [mcve] that reproduces the problem. Having to piece together the clues is only going to make finding a resolution harder. update the OP with the necessary information

Comment: ok have done that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For in-memory server testing The following utility class was created. It basically wraps the setup functionality in the example shown.

```
internal interface IHttpTestServer : IDisposable {
    HttpConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    HttpClient CreateClient();
}

internal class HttpTestServer : IHttpTestServer {
    HttpServer httpServer;

    public HttpTestServer(HttpConfiguration configuration = null) {
        httpServer = new HttpServer(configuration ?? new HttpConfiguration());
    }

    public HttpConfiguration Configuration {
        get { return httpServer.Configuration; }
    }

    public HttpClient CreateClient() {
        var client = new HttpClient(httpServer);
        return client;
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        if (httpServer != null) {
            httpServer.Dispose();
            httpServer = null;
        }
    }

    public static IHttpTestServer Create(HttpConfiguration configuration = null) {
        return new HttpTestServer(configuration);
    }
}
```

The following test was crafted to demonstrate the use of in memory server using OP

```
[TestClass]
public class IntegrationTests {

    [TestMethod]
    public async Task Test() {


        using (var server = HttpTestServer.Create()) {
            //Arrange
            var config = server.Configuration;
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            config.EnsureInitialized();

            var client = server.CreateClient();
            var url = "http://localhost/test";
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
            var expected = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK;

            //Act
            var result = await client.SendAsync(request, CancellationToken.None);

            //Assert
            Assert.IsNotNull(result);
            Assert.AreEqual(expected, result.StatusCode);
        }

    }

    public class CVController : ApiController {
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("test")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> test() {
            return Ok();
        }
    }
}
```

Test passes.

The thing about this example is that the test and controller exist in same assembly so map attribute scans the assembly it was called in and found API controller with attribute routes. If controller lived in another project then the web API config of that project should be called on the `HttpConfiguration` to properly configure web API.

**UPDATE**

The test project and web api project should be two separate projects. That said, The web project should have a `WebApiConfig.cs` file with a static `WebApiConfig.Register` class and method. That method takes a `HttpConfiguration` parameter. The test should use that method to configure the api for in memory calls.

```
[TestClass]
public class IntegrationTests {

    [TestMethod]
    public async Task Test() {


        using (var server = HttpTestServer.Create()) {
            //Arrange
            var config = server.Configuration;
            //Config server
            MyWebApiNamespace.WebApiConfig.Register(config);

            var client = server.CreateClient();
            var url = "http://localhost/test";
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
            var expected = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK;

            //Act
            var result = await client.SendAsync(request, CancellationToken.None);

            //Assert
            Assert.IsNotNull(result);
            Assert.AreEqual(expected, result.StatusCode);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok thank you are you able to elaborate on what you meant by "If controller lived in another project then the web API config of that project should be called on the HttpConfiguration to properly configure web API." I think that is the exact problem because when I debug my server there is only one route there (/)

Comment: Using your example worked by the way providing that I have the controller in the same project - since it will sit in a seperate project how should I be calling the web api config on my httpconfiguration?

Comment: Thanks for all the effort it is all working now - great answer.